# do not remove previous point in spline highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

in splin highchart when draw new live point,it remove first point from left.

[image]

how can i disable this work in highchart

my chart must be in fix datetime range,and live splin chart must begin in min datetime and finish in max datetime.and do not remove any point.

when recieve to max datetime the point must be clear.

```
$(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });

            $('#LineChart').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline',
                    zoomType: 'x',
                    resetZoomButton: {
                        position: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: -30
                        }
                    },
                    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                    marginRight: 10,
                    events: {
                        load: function () {
                            var seri = new Array();
                            seri = this.series;
                            setInterval(function () {
                                var result = ReadAlarmTypes();
                                var j = 0;
                                $.each(result, function (index, AlarmTypes) {
                                    var AlarmName = AlarmTypes.AlarmName;
                                    var AlarmTypeId = AlarmTypes.AlarmTypeId;
                                    //Read Last Device's Log Value
                                    var signals = ReadLatestLogs(AlarmTypeId);
                                    if (signals != null) {
                                        $.each(signals, function (index, signal) {
                                            var series1 = seri[j];
                                            var x = (new Date(signal.DateTime)).getTime(), // current time
                                            y = signal.Value;
                                            series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                                        });
                                    }
                                    j++;
                                });
                            }, 5000);
                        }
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Live random data'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150
                    //min: (new Date(GetShiftTime())).getTime()
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                series: getSeri('Online')
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your condition to remove from left or not, if you need to remove call :

```
series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
```

else call:

```
series1.addPoint([x, y], true, false);
```